# Does boost have an "compact optional" where presence is encoded by special value of type?

Tags: c++, boost, stdoptional

I am looking for space efficient implementation of optional (`sizeof small_optional<T> == sizeof (T)`).
So the emptiness is encoded using some special value of T, for example

```
small_optional<int, -1>
```

requires that I never store -1 in the small_optional so -1 can be used as magic value to determine if optional is empty or not.

Comment: I've never come across anything like this. The nearest thing I guess is `npos` in the C++ standard library. Out of interest, what would happen to 2 - 3 in your particular case, or is your class limited to storage and not arithmetic operations?

Comment: boost does this for reference types. optional value is stored as null

Comment: @Bathsheba UB would happen... :)  But in some cases it is valuable, for example index of an array(I can use uint32_t max as magic values if I know my arrays are smaller than 4Gitems)

Comment: @dfri sorry, forgot to accept after I upvoted. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [markable](https://github.com/akrzemi1/markable) lib was created for this sole purpose:

> ### Markable 1.0.0
>
> An alternative to `boost::optional<T>` which does not store an additional `bool` flag, but encodes the 'empty' state inside `T` using a special indicated value.
>
> #### Usage
>
> Do you want to store a possibly missing `int`? Can you spare value `-1`?
> You can use it like this:
>
> ```
> using namespace ak_toolkit;
> typedef markable<mark_int<int, -1>> opt_int;
>
> opt_int oi;
> opt_int o2 (2);
>
> assert (!oi.has_value());
> assert (o2.has_value());
> assert (o2.value() == 2);
>
> static_assert (sizeof(opt_int) == sizeof(int), "");
> ```
>
> Do you want to store a possibly missing `std::string`, where 'missing'
> != 'empty'? Can you spare some string values that contain a null
> character inside, like `std::string("\0\0", 2)`? This is how you do
> it:
>
> ```
> struct string_marked_value                           // a policy which defines the representaioion of the
>   : ak_toolkit::markable_type<std::string>           // 'marked' (special) std::string value
> {               
>   static std::string marked_value() {                // create the marked value
>     return std::string("\0\0", 2);
>   }
>   static bool is_marked_value(const std::string& v) { // test if a given value is considered marked
>     return v.compare(0, v.npos, "\0\0", 2) == 0;
>   }
> };
>
> typedef ak_toolkit::markable<string_marked_value> opt_str;
> opt_str os, oE(std::string(""));
>
> assert (!os.has_value());
> assert (oE.has_value());
> assert (oE.value() == "");
>
> static_assert (sizeof(opt_str) == sizeof(std::string), "");
> ```

Albeit not a Boost library, markable is licensed under [Boost Software License, Version 1.0.](http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt), and is even referred to from the [*Performance Considerations*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/performance_considerations.html) section of Boosts own optional type:

> ### Performance considerations
>
> [...]
>
> #### Controlling the size
>
> [...] Therefore, **if the size of the objects is critical for your
> application** (e.g., because you want to utilize your CPU cache in
> order to gain performance) **and** you have determined **you are willing to
> trade the code clarity**, **it is recommended that you** simply go with
> type `int` and use some 'magic value' to represent not-an-int, **or
> use something like [markable](https://github.com/akrzemi1/markable)
> library.**

---

The background and thought process of the lib is explained in the following blog post from the lib's author:

- [Andrzej's C++ blog - Efficient optional values](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/efficient-optional-values/)

Comment: Since the special value is stored inside the marked object, does it mean it doubles the memory usage?

Comment: @luizfls No. The special value is encoded in _the type_, not  duplicated for every object of said type. For e.g. an integral type this is zero-cost as the special value can be encoded as a non-type template parameter in the encoded type. For e.g. a markable `std::string` the memory cost will be a single `std::string` object (stored in a .bss segment) for _the type_, but this will not duplicate over several instances of the type. This approach is, in essence, zero-cost w.r.t. extra memory usage but at the cost of worse semantics.

Comment: Alright! I didn't realize template parameters were stored at "type level" rather than "object level"; neat!